# Is this json validate to use a Map in the field detail

Tags: java, json, maven, dictionary, jackson

I must do a concept test to get a json structure and convert in object in java like this Map<String,Double> with Jackson. But the data has these format:

````
 ```
"reversedSellId": "reversed trxId from PayU", "merchant":"idMerchant",
"detail": {
    LOAN_CAPITAL: 1234,123,
    LOAN_INTEREST: 1234,123,
    LOAN_ADMON_FEE: 1234,123,
    LOAN_IVA_ADMON_FEE: 1234,123,
    LOAN_OVERDUE_INTEREST: 0,
    LOAN_COLLECTION_MANAGEMENT: 0,
    LOAN_IVA_COLLECTION_MANAGEMENT: 0
},
  "currency": "COP"
}```
````

But When put this Json in a Json reader formatted is no allow because its structured is incorrect. So I need know really how would be the structure correct.

Thanks. Is in Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid JSON format:

```
{
    "reversedSellId": "reversed trxId from PayU",
    "merchant": "idMerchant",
    "detail": {
        "LOAN_CAPITAL": 1234.123,
        "LOAN_INTEREST": 1234.123,
        "LOAN_ADMON_FEE": 1234.123,
        "LOAN_IVA_ADMON_FEE": 1234.123,
        "LOAN_OVERDUE_INTEREST": 0,
        "LOAN_COLLECTION_MANAGEMENT": 0,
        "LOAN_IVA_COLLECTION_MANAGEMENT": 0
    },
    "currency": "COP"
}
```